# How to get all numbers AND IPs from string using regex?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, xml

Let's say I have the following example string:

```
<ETH0_IP><![CDATA[10.0.100.10]]></ETH0_IP>
```

I would like to **extract** the **first number** **and** the **IP** in the following format:

```
0 10.0.100.10
```

I do know how to extract the first (`sed 's@^[^0-255]*\([0-255]\+\).*@\1@'`) number and IPs (`grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'`), but **one at the time** and I was wondering if I can achieve it in just one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all (integer) numbers and all IP(v4) addresses, add an alternation to the regex with grep:

```
... | grep -oE '[0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

This would print the values one per line, and would of course  also catch the `0` from the `ETH0` at the end.

---

If you want just the number and the IP from input lines that contain a  similar structure as the above (and no others) you could use e.g. sed:

```
... | sed -nEe 's,.*<ETH([0-9]+)_IP><!\[CDATA\[([0-9.]+)\]\]></ETH[0-9]+_IP>.*,\1 \2,p'
```

`\1` and `\2` correspond to the first and second group in parenthesis, and I matched the IP with just `[0-9.]+` here for both clarity and laziness.

---

or similarly in  Perl:

```
... | perl -ne 'print "$1 $2\n" if m,<ETH([0-9]+)_IP><!\[CDATA\[([0-9.]+)\]\]></ETH[0-9]+_IP>,'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all non digit (and not ".") characters to spaces and then you can print out the first and 2nd columns:

```
echo '<ETH0_IP><![CDATA[10.0.100.10]]></ETH0_IP>' | \
   sed -re 's;[^0-9.]; ;g' | \
   awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

output:

```
0 10.0.100.10
```

ps: you have to make it more sophisticated if you have "." elsewhere and not only in the IPs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xq` (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), and assuming that the input is literally the single XML node from the question:

```bash
xq -r 'to_entries[] | [ (.key|ltrimstr("ETH")|rtrimstr("_IP")), .value ] | @tsv' file.xml
```

This converts the XML document into JSON, and then extracts the remainder from the tag name by stripping off `ETH` from the start and `_IP` from the end.  The IP address is also extracted and the two resulting values are outputted as a tab-delimited list.

The `ltrimstr()` and `rtrimstr()` calls could possibly be replaced by `gsub("[^[:digit:]]"; ""))` or `gsub("\\D"; ""))`, which would delete all non-digits from the tag name.

The intermediate JSON document would look like

```json
{
  "ETH0_IP": "10.0.100.10"
}
```

... and the output would at the end would be

```
0       10.0.100.10
```